# Keep record of launched activities in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter

I was wondering how to keep a record of launched activites for logging purposes. what broadcast receiver I have to subscribe to intercept this intent? or what intent-filter to use? I figure that I must use some type of long-running service in the background.

My first objetive is to track main-focus applications, some sort of history.

Want to get finally some similar to:

- - Launched app com.android.xxx
- - Launched app xx.yy.zz
- - App xx.yy.zz lost focus

Thanks in advance

EDIT - Just see that app [MyAppRank](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.carbonbyte.myapprank) , that does exactly what i mean

Comment: you need actually the list of running applications from a device?

Comment: no, not really. i was heading more to a timeline of activities opened by user/with primary focus, for user usage statistics

Comment: I am not sure if there is API for this, but I'll add your question as a favorite since you made me curious

Comment: thanks!! i don't think there is an API, but a broadcastreceiver in the manifest or in a running service for intercept "startActivity(intent)" or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `Intent`s broadcast when applications are started or when applications come to the foreground. There isn't anything that you can hook into as a listener to get these events.

The way you can do this (which is the way apps like MyAppRank do it) is to use the methods of the `ActivityManager`:

```
getRunningTasks()
getRunningAppProcesses()
getRecentTasks()
```

You create a `Service` which runs all the time and at regular intervals calls methods of the `ActvityManager` to determine which task is in the foreground and you can "infer" what the user has done (or is doing). It isn't an exact science.

Note: You will need `android.permission.GET_TASKS` and none of this works anymore as of API 21 (Android 5, Lollipop). As of API 21 the security has been tightened and an application can only get information about its own tasks, not other tasks in the system.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, it's a shame (for my purpose) the 5.0+ limitation, but it's ok for security. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

What i'm able to figure out from your question is that you want to **keep track of all the activities when they are launched in your application**. If that is correct, the solution may work for you:

1. Crate a **BaseActivity** which all of your Activities should extend

   ```
   public class BaseActivity extends Activity
   ```

   {

   ```
   private Activity activity;

   public static final String INTENTFILTER_TRACK_MY_ACTIVITIES="INTENTFILTER_TRACK_MY_ACTIVITIES";
   public static final String INTENTFILTER_REMOVE_MY_ACTIVITIES="INTENTFILTER_REMOVE_MY_ACTIVITIES";

   public void setActivity(Activity act)
   {
       activity = act;
   }

   public Activity getActivity()
   {
       return activity;
   }

   @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setAction(INTENTFILTER_TRACK_MY_ACTIVITIES);
       intent.putExtra("activityName", activity.getClass().getSimpleName());
       sendBroadcast(intent);
   }

   @Override protected void onDestroy()
   {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onDestroy();
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setAction(INTENTFILTER_REMOVE_MY_ACTIVITIES);
       intent.putExtra("activityName", activity.getClass().getSimpleName());
       sendBroadcast(intent);
       setActivity(null);
   }
   ```

   }
2. Now extend above BaseActivity for all your activities. i.e instead of extending your Activities should extend BaseActivity and call **setActivity(this);** in onCreate like below:

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity
   ```

{

```
     @Override      
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setActivity(this);
        //write your other code form here
    }

}
```

3.Then write a BroadcastReceiver like below:

```
   class TrackActivitiesReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {

private static final Object SEPERATOR = ",";// use , as seperator 
String sb="";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(BaseActivity.INTENTFILTER_TRACK_MY_ACTIVITIES))
    {
        sb+=intent.getStringExtra("activityName");
        sb+=SEPERATOR;
    }
    else if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(BaseActivity.INTENTFILTER_REMOVE_MY_ACTIVITIES))
    {
        sb=sb.replace(intent.getStringExtra("activityName")+SEPERATOR, "");
    }
}}
```

4Finally, Register above Receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <receiver
        android:name="TrackActivitiesReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="INTENTFILTER_TRACK_MY_ACTIVITIES" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Hope this solves your problem. cheers!

Comment: I understood he needs to keep a statistic will all activities launched from the device (no matter the app).

Comment: @gunar exactly, trying to keep app opened records e.g. opened calendar, opened twitter app, opened facebook... or a record of apps with primary focus. Vinay, great response BTW

Comment: This is the answer that many searching today are likely looking for